# Is it possible for the sum of two independent random variables (where at least one of them is not normal) to sum to a normal random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a normal random variable. Suppose we have the following decomposition:
$$
X = Y + Z
$$
where $Y$ ad $Z$ are independent. Is it possible for either $Y$ or $Z$ to be not normal?

I suspect yes but am having trouble coming up with a counter example.

Comment: The parenthetical remark in the title must be a mistake.

Comment: Fixed typo in heading

Comment: This is lame and might not work but what if $Y$ is a constant RV that equals 7 with probability one. Then $X +Y$ is normal with the mean shifted by 7. So yes it is possible.

Comment: But you can think of this $Y\sim N(7,0)$, without much headache.

Comment: @kimchilover great point, you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
It is a famous result of Cramér that if the sum of two independent random variables $X + Y$ is a normal random variable, then $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed as well.

This is a difficult result whose proof uses the machinery of complex analysis. The original paper can be found [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01180430) and the wikipedia page for this result [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%99s_decomposition_theorem)